# SQL query with complex boolean expression as a column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following tables in my PostgreSQL database:

- classes: Containing class_id and other fields
- athletes: Containing athlete_id and other fields
- classes_athletes: This is a many to many relationship between classes and athletes. It contains for each class_id which athlete_id are enrolled. In my case it looks like this:

```
select * FROM classes_athletes;

          class_id | athlete_id
-------------------+------------
                 2 |          1
                 2 |          2
                 2 |          3
                 2 |          4
                 2 |          5
                 1 |          1
                 1 |          2
                 1 |          3
                 1 |          4
```

Now what I would like to do is to create an SQL query which I can use to indicate if a class contains or not a certain athlete. Here are some examples based on the data above:

```
For athlete_id=1 it should return
 class_id | athleteIsEnrolled
----------+------------------
        1 |          1
        2 |          1

For athlete_id=99 it should return
 class_id | athleteIsEnrolled
----------+------------------
        1 |          0
        2 |          0
```

I Tried the following sql query but it returns a value for each entry of classes_athletes instead of only one for each unique class_id:

```
SELECT c.class_id, CAST(CASE WHEN athlete_id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS bit) as athleteEnrolled
FROM classes_athletes  as c;
```

And the result is:

```
          class_id | athleteEnrolled
-------------------+-----------------
                 2 | 1
                 2 | 0
                 2 | 0
                 2 | 0
                 2 | 0
                 1 | 1
                 1 | 0
                 1 | 0
                 1 | 0
```

Comment: Have you tried just adding a distinct to your last select statement?

Answer (score 1):

Using a left join approach:

```sql
SELECT
    c.class_id,
    COUNT(ca.class_id) AS athleteEnrolled
FROM classes c
LEFT JOIN classes_athletes ca
    ON ca.class_id = c.class_id AND
       ca.athlete_id = 1
GROUP BY
    c.class_id
ORDER BY
    c.class_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the conditional aggregation as follows:

```
SELECT c.class_id, Count(1) as athleteEnrolled
FROM classes c 
left join classes_athletes ca 
  on c.class_id = ca.class_id
 and ca.athlete_id = 1
Group by c.class_id;
```

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen for noticing. Answer is updated!!

Answer (score 0):

Using a subquery approach:

```sql
SELECT 
  class_id,
  (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM classes_athletes AS enrollment 
    WHERE enrollment.class_id = classes.class_id AND athlete_id = 99
  ) AS athleteEnrolled
FROM classes
ORDER BY class_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT c.class_id,
  EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM classes_athletes ca 
    WHERE ca.class_id = c.class_id AND athlete_id = ?
  ) athleteEnrolled
FROM classes c
```

Replace `?` with the `athlete_id` you search for.
This query returns a boolean result `true` or `false`.
If you want the result as an integer `1` or `0` you can cast it to integer with `::int`

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=360badaf2a318562e350f8ebb56a00a0).